# Can someone please check my timer program in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that checks if the changes in the values of X,Y and Z don't exceed a difference of 10 within 5 seconds, the initialValues() function should be called.

I have written the following program but it crashes while running and the program doesn't work. Then I have to force close the program.

below is the main part of my program for timer. My program doesn't crash when I remove this specific part.

How do I fix this?

```
 while(X<=X+10 || X>=X-10 && Y<=Y+10 || Y>=Y-10 && Z<=Z+10 || Z>=Z-10)
   {
       clock_t t;
       t = clock();
       t = clock()-t;
       float timer = t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       if(timer==5)
       {
           initialValues(X,Y,Z);
           cout<<"X = "<<initialX<<" Y = "<<initialY<<" Z = "<<initialZ<<endl;
       }
   }
```

Comment: how should i put it... your while has condition which is equivalent to : `0 <= 10 || 0 >= -10 && 0<= 10 || 0 >= -10 && 0<=10 || 0>=-10`, which is always true

Comment: I suppose you mean "after 5 seconds" rather than "within 5 seconds", since there's no way to reliably check whether a variable has been modified. Looking at your code, I would recommend you return to your book and study how variables and loops work. In particular, why `x <= x + 10` is always true and why `timer` will never have a value other than 0.

Comment: Also, you're comparing a `float` value `timer` to another value with equality. [It will give you wrong results](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). You probably meant `if(timer>=5)` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the function initialValues does, so we cannot know whether something dodgy is done there.
However, it seems likely that you have an infinite loop. Check the conditions in the while loop, and insert brackets to separate conditions that should be evaluated together, such as, for exmaple:

```
while( ( X<=X+10 || X>=X-10 ) && ( Y<=Y+10 || Y>=Y-10 ) && ( Z<=Z+10 || Z>=Z-10) )
```

Note the extra brackets.

In particular, you should check whether the conditions that you have specified are always true, as suggested by another user. It seems to me that X<=X+10 always, and the same applies to the rest of conditions.

Comment: Can you please tell if that algorithm that I have used for timer is correct? The initialValues() assigns the initial values of X,Y and Z to variables initialX, initialY and initialZ. I am sure the initialValues() function doesn't have any error.

Comment: I can say without a shadow of a doubt that the condition in your while loop is always true. Hence the loop will be executed forever, possibly causing your program to hang. I cannot tell you how to solve the problem because you haven't explained enough of what you're trying to do. But for sure you need to change the conditions in your loop.